# Datatables serverside processing using mysqli json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am using datatables without a problem, but some pages crash due to the large amount of data that it's fetching from the database. So I tried to implement server side processing. I followed the examples on the site, but I just don't seem to receive the json data sent from the php file. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

What I get on console is: `jquery.min.js:5 POST http://example.com//datatables-script.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Response at Network tab says: `Failed to load response data`
This is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sort').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "datatables-script.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {storeid:'<?php echo $stid; ?>'},
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(gotback) {
                //var JSONArray = JSON.stringify(data);
                //console.log(JSONArray);
                console.log(gotback);
            }
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
    });
```

This is my script: Sorry for the long post.

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$aColumns = array( 'Rec_Id', 'Br_Id', 'C_Id', 'SubcId', 'ProdId', 'Prodme', 'URL', 'Im0', 'Price' );

$sIndexColumn = 'Rec_Id';
$sTable = 'tb';

$gaSql['user'] = 'ss';
$gaSql['password'] = 'sss';
$gaSql['db'] = 's';
$gaSql['server'] = 's';
$gaSql['port'] = 3306; // 3306 is the default MySQL port

// Input method (use $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST)
$input =& $_POST;

$gaSql['charset'] = 'utf8';

//get store id
$storeid = $_POST['storeid'];
$db = new mysqli($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password'], $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['port']);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die( 'Error connecting to MySQL server (' . mysqli_connect_errno() .') '. mysqli_connect_error() );
}

if (!$db->set_charset($gaSql['charset'])) {
    die( 'Error loading character set "'.$gaSql['charset'].'": '.$db->error );
}

$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $input['iDisplayStart'] ) && $input['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
    $sLimit = " LIMIT ".intval( $input['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $input['iDisplayLength'] );
}

$aOrderingRules = array();
if ( isset( $input['iSortCol_0'] ) ) {
    $iSortingCols = intval( $input['iSortingCols'] );
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iSortingCols ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $input[ 'bSortable_'.intval($input['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == 'true' ) {
            $aOrderingRules[] =
                "".$aColumns[ intval( $input['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]." "
                .($input['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($aOrderingRules)) {
    $sOrder = " ORDER BY ".implode(", ", $aOrderingRules);
} else {
    $sOrder = "";
}

$iColumnCount = count($aColumns);

if ( isset($input['sSearch']) && $input['sSearch'] != "" ) {
    $aFilteringRules = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($input['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true' ) {
            $aFilteringRules[] = "".$aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string( $input['sSearch'] )."%'";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($aFilteringRules)) {
        $aFilteringRules = array('('.implode(" OR ", $aFilteringRules).')');
    }
}

// Individual column filtering
for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
    if ( isset($input['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $input['bSearchable_'.$i] == 'true' && $input['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
        $aFilteringRules[] = "".$aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string($input['sSearch_'.$i])."%'";
    }
}

if (!empty($aFilteringRules)) {
    $sWhere = " WHERE sid=$storeid ".implode(" AND ", $aFilteringRules);
} else {
    $sWhere = "";

    $aQueryColumns = array();
    foreach ($aColumns as $col) {
        if ($col != ' ') {
            $aQueryColumns[] = $col;
        }
    }

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", $aQueryColumns)."
        FROM ".$sTable."".$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
        //echo $sQuery;
    $rResult = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);

    // Data set length after filtering
    $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);
    list($iFilteredTotal) = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_row();

    // Total data set length
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.") FROM ".$sTable."";
    $rResultTotal = $db->query( $sQuery ) or die($db->error);
    list($iTotal) = $rResultTotal->fetch_row();

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($input['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array(),
    );

    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<$iColumnCount ; $i++ ) {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == 'version' ) {
                // Special output formatting for 'version' column
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=='0') ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            } elseif ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' ) {
                // General output
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: I would like to recommend using code indentation. I did it for you this time. As you can see, you're not closing the jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){` function and your PHP file is still inside the `if() { .. } else { ...` condition when you're trying to `echo` the response. You're also not closing PHP: `?>` I'm not saying this is the cause of your problem. I am saying these are mistakes you need to correct.

Comment: You are using old `datatable` initialisation. You should remove `serverSide`, `processing` and `ajax` and replace them with their proper alternatives according to the documentation. Also, for **server side processing** the `JSON` output must return some necessary parameters.

Comment: @philantrovert I got this script from their documentation too and it says that it's an updated code of which was mysql before. It has been updated to mysqli OO

Comment: @YohanBlake Are you talking about [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: @philantrovert yes, but isn't that code, and the ssp.class.php incuded in it, the same in a different sql format? I'm more familiar with mysqli, and that's why I thought of using it

Comment: @YohanBlake I don't know Php so I'd rather not comment on that. Try to match the output of your Php file to that of the standard data table server side output.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, I am using the same in my project:

JS:

```
$('#datatable_location_details').dataTable({
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "getdetails.php,
    // "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null, { "bSortable": true, "sClass": "align_center" }, { "bSortable": true, "sClass": "align_center" }, { "bSortable": false, "sClass": "align_center" }]
});
```

Php:

```
$start  = $_REQUEST['iDisplayStart'];
$length = $_REQUEST['iDisplayLength'];
$col = $_REQUEST['iSortCol_0'];

$arr = array(0 => 'state', 1 => 'city', 2 => 'institute_name', 3 => 'address', 4 => 'student_count', 5 => 'ranking');

$sort_by = $arr[$col];
$sort_type = $_REQUEST['sSortDir_0'];

$qry = "select id, institute_name, address, state, city, student_count, ranking, latitude, longitude from location_details where (state LIKE '%".$state."%' and city LIKE '%".$city."%' and institute_name LIKE '%".$name."%' and address LIKE '%".$address."%') and (address != '' and state != '' and city != '') ORDER BY ".$sort_by." ".$sort_type." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$length;

$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}

$qry = "select count(id) as count from location_details";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $iTotal = $row['count'];
}

$rec = array(
    'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iTotal,
    'aaData' => array()
);

$k=0;
if (isset($data) && is_array($data))
{
    foreach ($data as $item)
    {
        $action = 'Show Map';
        $tooltip= 'Show Map';
        $class  = 'show_details';
        if($item['latitude'] == '' && $item['longitude'] == '')
        {
            $action = 'Modify Address';
            $tooltip= 'Latitude & Longitude are not available for this address';
            $class  = 'modify_address';
        }
        $rec['aaData'][$k] = array(
            0 => $item['state'],
            1 => $item['city'],
            2 => htmlspecialchars($item['institute_name'], ENT_QUOTES),
            3 => htmlspecialchars($item['address'], ENT_QUOTES),
            4 => $item['student_count'],
            5 => $item['ranking'],
            6 => '<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="'.$tooltip.'" class="'.$class.'" id="'.$item['id'].'">'.$action.'</a>',
        );
        $k++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($rec);
```

For more info check this [Github Project](https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing)

Comment: Although this might help OP solve his problem, I hope you do realise this isn't an answer to the question. At best, it can be an indirect solution.

Comment: Ya I know, but I cant post the whole code in comment, and it's a working example. The github link is also of my account.

Comment: I know. I'm not saying it was wrong to turn this into an answer. I'm just clerifying it a bit in light of: `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, at first glance, did you see anything wrong in my code? I have posted the whole code here.